# Display Result From one column in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have one table stores Row Id and Col Id for different Item Name and Related Quantity....which is described as follows....

```
RowId   ColID   Value
3         2     Laptop
4         2     Mouse
4         4      80
3         4      50
```

I need output:

```
Value   Qty
Laptop  50
Mouse   80
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT a.value AS Value, b.value AS Qty
FROM 
(SELECT RowId, VALUE FROM test WHERE COLID = 2 ORDER BY ROWID) a,
(SELECT RowId, VALUE FROM test WHERE COLID = 4 ORDER BY ROWID) b
WHERE a.rowid = b.rowid
```